# No handler for UDF/UDAF/UDTF - Spark UDF3

Tags: java, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

**Java Code -**

```
package ClusterAlgoCall2;

import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import org.apache.spark.sql.api.java.UDF3;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes;

public class ClusterAlgocall_Main3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("someappname").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate();

    UDF3 UDFCosinetoTxt = new UDF3<String, String, String, String>() {
        public String call(String col1, String col2 , String col3) throws Exception {
            return col3  ;
        }
    };
    spark.udf().register("UDFCosinetoTxt", UDFCosinetoTxt, DataTypes.StringType);
}
}
```

**Built it & created a jar for it. Tried to use this jar in spark-SQL**
**After creating a temp function using -**

```
add jar s3://xxxx/jar/ClusterAlgoCall2.jar ;
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION ClusterAlgo as 'ClusterAlgoCall2.ClusterAlgocall_Main3' using jar 's3://xxxx/jar/ClusterAlgoCall2.jar';
```

**Error While running Query -**

```
select ClusterAlgo2(col1,col2,col3) from clusteralgo_test ;
Error in query: No handler for UDF/UDAF/UDTF 'ClusterAlgoCall2.ClusterAlgocall_Main3'; line 1 pos 7
```

Comment: Hi @aggrawalnikhil02, have you found a solution? I'm having the same problem..

Answer (score 0):

To create UDFs the Java class needs to follow a specific pattern.
According to the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0-preview/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-create-function.html), the implementing class should extend one of the base classes:

> `class_name`
>
> Specifies the name of the class that provides the implementation for function to be created. The implementing class should extend one of the base classes as follows:
>
> - Should extend `UDF` or `UDAF` in `org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec` package.
> - Should extend `AbstractGenericUDAFResolver`, `GenericUDF`, or `GenericUDTF` in `org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic` package.
> - Should extend `UserDefinedAggregateFunction` in `org.apache.spark.sql.expressions` package.

Therefore, for example, your class definition should look like:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDF;

public class ClusterAlgocall_Main3 extends UDF { ... }
```

[Here](https://github.com/curtishoward/sparkudfexamples/blob/master/hive-udf/src/main/java/com/cloudera/fce/curtis/sparkudfexamples/hiveudf/CTOF.java) is an example.